# Get Post ID as a separate RSS feed item

Tags: wp-query, rss, xml

I am looking for a way to display or echo each post ID within my RSS feed. Basically when I access [my RSS feed site](http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/feed/), I get the following XML items: `<title>`, `<link>`, `<comments>`, `<category>`, `<pubDate>`, `<guid isPermaLink>`, `<description>`.

When I use this Google function in my code

```
var url = 'http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/feed/';
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
```

the returned Objects are title, link, author, publishedDate, contentSnippet...

What I also want returned is the Post ID but not sure how to get my WordPress to include that in the XML.

Comment: Anyone able to help or point me in the right direction

Comment: check out your `guid` tags in your feed, they include the post id's ( `...?p=123` )

Comment: Yes I know but Google Feed API does not pick it up. How do I get it to pick anything after ...?p=

Comment: One can easily add an extra custom tag to the feed, but it will not give you a valid feed structure, so I think using the guid instead might be a better option. You might try javascript regex to strip out the post ID from the guid.

Comment: Thanks birgire, your comment gave me an idea which I will post as my answer

Answer (score 1):

How did I workaround this?

Step1: From my WordPress Permalink Settings, I selected Custom Structure and added /%post_id%/
This means my results will be in this format:

```
<myurl>/<postID>
```

Step2: To make it easier for me instead of writing a regex query I used a a Split command like this:

```
var postlink = entry.link;
var id = postlink.split(/\//)[3];
```

**(///)[3]** would simply split the URL by the number of slashes and take only that 3rd bit which is where my postID is.

I hope this comes in handy for others in my position.